# About UK driving license

Tags: health, driving-licenses

I am planning to  accure a driving license from UK. But my left eye is completed blank. In this case, is there any chance to get a driving license from UK?. I am not considered as a disability person in India. Doctors won't gives 40% disability certificates. What are the procedure I need to follow to get a driving license in UK.

Comment: Are you living in the UK, or in India? Do you have an Indian driving license that you're hoping to exchange? What do you mean by `accure a driving license` ?

Comment: I don't have any indian driving license. But have experience in driving in india.  No license. There is very difficult  for me to get a license.

Comment: To get a UK driving license you need to be a resident here (in which case the question is off topic for this site...) If you're not a UK resident then the answer to your question is simple: there are no procedures to follow, you're not able to get a UK driving license.

Comment: @djr Good point. I'd assumed there was an intention to do this as a temporary resident (not much point otherwise)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you otherwise meet the sight requirements, partial vision in one eye (or even loss of one eye completely) won't prevent people getting a UK driving licence, though they need to consult an optician and inform the authorities of the situation:

https://www.gov.uk/driving-eyesight-rules

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/a-guide-to-standards-of-vision-for-driving-cars-and-motorcycles-group-1

https://help.rnib.org.uk/help/daily-living/transport-travel/monocular-drive

Given this, you can presumably get a UK license in the same way as anyone else resident in the UK who doesn't have one & doesn't have an overseas license:

https://www.gov.uk/apply-first-provisional-driving-licence

I would recommend that you first go and speak to a UK optician who will be able to verify whether you meet the eyesight requirements (they're used to checking this).